# Replication with pull subscribers fails under Active Directory policy when using a dedicated replication account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, replication, pull

I have a replication set up with pull subscribers and it's deployed in our corporate domain. I have requested to create a dedicated account to run this replication off of.

On a pull subscription client in Sql Agent job I get this error:

**Message
Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Error authenticating proxy DOMAIN\username, system error: Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer. ('Access this computer from network')).  The step failed.**

Where DOMAIN - is my domain name and username is this replication username that I requested from our admins.

This replication user can access both the distributor and the share folder where snapshots are stored. It also has this specific permission 'Access this computer from network' inherited from the group it's in.

Anyone encounter this sort of problem?

Comment: faved because i'm just starting to get into replication.  :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the requested user wasn't added to a group that has all the necessary permissions. And so I've been struggling with this problem for several hours at which point I decided to go to our network administrator and see to it that the user was actually in the proper group. So yeah, I guess the message is right, a user has to have this permission **'Access this computer from network'**. So, this basically answers my own question. Phew!